# Python CGI Script is not rendering at all

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cgi, aws-cloudformation

I am working on running python -m CGIHTTPServer 80 from an ec2 instance. I have a folder within the current directory called cgi-bin. In cgi-bin, there is a file called hello.py. I have made both of them executable. However, when I open up the server in a browser, there is just a blank screen. Note that I am working from a linux ec2 instance. Also, I am running the python -m CGIHTTPServer 80 command from the userdata of my Cloudformation Template.

Comment: What does your script do? What output are you expecting from executing hello.py?

Comment: @Joe I think I figured out why it does not work. My userdata is executing everything as root. Is there any way not to perform all of the commands in the userdata section as ec2-user? For instance, one of my commands is git cloning a repository, but this is done as root. It should be done as ec2-user.

Comment: You can use `sudo -u ec2-user my command`

Comment: @kichik I believe I get a network error when I try this

Comment: Are you talking about host resolution errors? Those might just be warnings.

Comment: @kichik The error I am getting is "Could not resolve host: github.com; Name or service not known"